# What font or typeface is used in this text that says "Johnson"?

Tags: font-identification

I am trying to identify what looks like a regular typeface for client.  This is from their logo, which they only have as an image.  I also included the full image, but I am not sure if the "J" is from the font or custom.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried asking the client? Or better, contacting the client's designer/marketing department? They would know for sure.

Comment: @Johannes You are assuming the client (a) knows (b) has a designer and/or a marketing department (c) has a designer who created the logo and didn't inherit it from someone who left no notes. Small clients frequently don't have that information, thus the OP is asking.

Comment: Okay, I shouldn't have said "know for sure" but instead "maybe they might know" -- I don't work as a designer so I guess it surprises me how much clients don't keep track of any of their assets or the people that would know.

Comment: Good suggestion, which I tried... Unfortunately, the client has no idea on the font and the designer is long gone.  Thanks.

Comment: If you view the full size version of the top image, you'll notice some wonky curves. That combined with the 'roundness' of all the terminals makes me think this is a freebie font or rip-off font that was done via auto-tracing.

Comment: There is also a slight possibility that it is not an italic font and the skew is custom. Looking at non italic fonts could help.

Comment: Even the year it was produced can help, as if it's, say, from the 90s we may be able to rule out the possibility it's a "font from a free fonts website".

Answer (score 3):

I have reason to believe the "h" has been modified too.  See how its x-height doesn't match the other letters and it looks a little ugly.

[image]

As well as the fact most fonts of this style seem to have a curved "h", like in Garamond Premier Pro:

[image]

Still, the emphasis on the "o" is different, and the tails on the "n" obviously are.

(I suspect the tails on characters like "h" and "n" have been messed with too, for what it's worth).

The emphasis on the "s" and "o" are more like Zapf Chancery, but obviously the "n"s don't match this.

In conclusion, I don't know what this font is, but it does seem a little like it may have been quite modified.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are looking at either:

- Admark Italic

[image]

- Agmena Book Italic

[image]

- Berling Regular Italic

[image]

*listed in the order of most probable to least because they are very similar fonts

**UPDATE:**
A more detailed heuristic check has yielded two other possibilities (or at least close derivatives of them) that share the key characteristics of `h` and also the `n` most closely.

- Cometa Cyrillic or Cometa Cyrillic Book Italics (a Web Font)

[image]

- Peleguer Italic
- Bible Script (a modified version to round the bases)

[image]

Comment: It certainly is not Plantin.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, the heuristic probably hit the non J portion a bit more and split the difference. I looked at the Adobe file on it, most everything matches except that elongated J. So possibly a derivative. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: No, all the letters are wrong. The most telling thing (apart from the J, which is almost certainly specially-drawn) is the rounded ends of the left legs of *h* and *n,* along with the straight ends of *s*.

Comment: @AndrewLeach, actually its not. I am going to post some images you can compare with the OP's image and see. I am not saying they are 100% but close enough. Of course we both accept that the J is stylized and more than certainly custom.

Comment: all close, but none are a match.

Comment: [Plantin Light Italic](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/mti/plantin/light-italic/) Note the *s* in particular.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I actually think the most telling bit is the right leg terminal on h and n, and it makes me think that the most likely one is actually the last in the list, Berling, and it's the reason that Agmena can be immediately ruled out.

Comment: Also, I'd like to comment that Plantin and Admark are 100% pixel for pixel identical, at least in these two samples.

Comment: Look at the tail on the "n".  It's definitely none of these, although Agmena Book Italic comes relatively close.  It's not Berling because of the serifs on the "s".

Comment: @DA01, you are correct. I stated that too, they are all very close but nothing is 100% as it seems some perspective corrections or whatever were used on the image generated by the original.

Comment: @KenB, that might have been a generation error on my part when I uploaded the images, I might have uploaded the same one twice, that could be my bad. I will regenerate them and upload them as soon as I can.

Comment: Bible Script is far too calligraphic. It would have to be very heavily modified, to the point where it simply becomes another font. Look at how extreme the stroke contrast is, especially on s and o. Plus, I think the stress on the o is more diagonal. The o in @user15757's sample has a much more stress.

Comment: @KenB, I agree, but there are enough structural elements to suggest that it could have been used and as I already stated modified to round the edges and probably skew the perspective as well. My goal has been to identify the underlying font, not how they stylized it to the final product that is posted by the OP. I don't think anyone simply types up something and converts it to image and says tada here you go. There HAS to be post processing.

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Well that's definitely not always true. There are plenty of corporations that use plain and simple text logos with no post processing whatsoever. Not to say that this is true in this case; my point here was just that I think other fonts would have been closer and taken less processing than Bible Script.

Comment: @KenB, I will take you at your word but not the fortune 500 I have done work with over 2 decades. The term corporation really doesn't mean anything given that anyone can incorporate a business, even if you have only 3 people. So not sure what standard you are using so I won't start an argument on that ;)

Comment: @GµårÐïåñ Hey, no argument that you are correct for the vast majority of cases. I'm just pointing out that it isn't universal. A good counter example is Time. If you head to Time.com, then open devtools and inspect their logo, you'll see that it's literally just text, not an image. Same goes for Slate (Slate.com).

Comment: @KenB, oh you flatterer. Sorry my friend, I misunderstood what you referred to as LOGO, my bad. I was referring to logos in the sense of branding images and for that even if its a simple text, styling goes into it. But if you mean logos like on the websites, then yes actually for SEO purposes many DO forgo their brand logos to simply use text as it is recognized by the engines easier. I didn't know you were referring to that and for that I am sorry. I though we were on the same page with regards to logos as in traditional branding images. You are correct, much of that is done with simple CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like custom font (or) drawing, searched everywhere nothing!!! and I'm sure character "J" is not a font, If you look closely, the curve looks twisted and off course like @GµårÐïåñ mentioned they are similar, but not the actual one. You need to create your own.

Still if you have doubt check the below screenshot, I tried with [What Font is](http://www.whatfontis.com/), but none of the font recognized except "O".

[image]

Comment: that's normal for WTF. It's a limitation of the OCR software. You need to manually tweak that in the tool. Drag the 3rd image onto the second image and it will combine them for you.